# Reference for one-dimensional polynomial dynamics?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, dynamical-systems

I was working on a problem for my Dynamical Systems class (essentially, using Lyapunov functions to prove that some square is in the basin of attraction of an equilibrium point) when I found myself trying to show some bound on the real roots of the function $f(x) = -\delta-3x+x^3$, where $0 < \delta < 2$. This devolved into a whole digression on the behavior of the roots of this function, which are really just the equilibria of the system $u' = -\delta-3u+u^3$ (the real and imaginary parts of which are plotted below as a function of $\delta$; ignore the colors a bit, as Mathematica doesn't really do strict path-following in calculating the values of Root[] objects):

[image]

At $\delta = \pm 2$, we have these pitchfork bifurcations (at least, I think they're pitchfork bifurcations). They represent values of $\delta$ where the discriminant of $-\delta-3x+x^3$ in $x$ crosses $0$. Firstly, how would I go about proving that these are pitchfork bifurcations using the normal form of the pitchfork bifurcation? Also, are there any good references on the dynamics of higher-degree one-dimensional polynomials (essentially, polynomial systems that don't have nice closed-form solutions like this one)? Thanks!

Edit: Thanks to [Moo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/295756/moo), I see how to show that these bifurcations are actually saddle-node bifurcations (which makes sense from the plots I provided... which I had been misreading. Doh!). I'd still love to have a good reference for the dynamics of one-dimensional high-degree polynomial systems, though!

Comment: Even the quadratic case is quite complicated as the [Logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) shows.

Comment: Yes, the logistic map is indeed very complicated, although I generally had continuous dynamical systems in mind. The continuous analogue of the logistic map (known as the logistic differential equation) is much simpler to describe in terms of its behavior on the phase line.

Comment: @MichaelLee: Did you try verifying all of the requirements of the formal definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitchfork_bifurcation#Formal_definition? This is Theorem 2.11: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m207/ch2.pdf

Comment: From the PDF you linked, it appears to me that the system doesn't satisfy the definition of a pitchfork bifurcation at $\delta = \pm 2$, $x = \mp 1$, but rather a saddle-node bifurcation. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: As for books, maybe you can peruse Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by  Strogatz, Dynamics and Bifurcations by Hale and Kocak, 
An Introduction to Dynamical Systems,  Arrowsmith and Place, Introduction to Applied Nonlinear Dynamical Systems and Chaos by Wiggins, Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields by Guckenheimer and Holmes, Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos by Hirsch , Smale and Devaney. Not sure if any of those will satisfy your request, but worth perusing and seeing if you like any of them.

Comment: @Moo ... also you've forgot about Meiss and Chicone :) I think that if OP  wants to dig into 1D maps, it might be useful to take a look at [*One-Dimensional Dynamics* by Welington de Melo and Sebastian van Strien](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~svanstri/Files/demelo-strien.pdf). As for dealing with first-order ODEs with higher-order polynomial as RHS, take any book on solving polynomial equations in one variable you like: it really boils down to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I've used Strogatz's book before, as well as Hirsch, Devaney, and Smale. I took a class with Guckenheimer, but we didn't use his book (quite unfortunately, as we ended up using some spectacularly awful preprint of a text by another author). I particularly liked Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems (by Katok and Hasselblatt) and Geometrical Methods in the Theory of Ordinary Differential Equations (Arnol'd). I'll definitely look at the rest, though!

Comment: @Evgeny: I am not familiar with Meiss or One Dimesional Dynamics - so I'll take a look at those. Chicone is not one of my favorites so I always forget about it. :-) Thanks for those data points!

Comment: @Moo Maybe I'm wrong, but my impression is that Chicone's book looks a bit overburdened with details at first sight. In the beginning it's overwhelming, in the end you don't always need all that stuff, but there is a some period when you seem to grasp the feeling of what is happening, but still want to understand it rigorously and see all the "well-it's-very-intuitive-skip-the-details" done with calculus or differential geometry or topology tools. And to me Chicone's book nicely fills that spot :)

Comment: @Evgeny: I suspect you are likely right as I must admit to not having spent nearly enough time with it. Maybe now I'll give it another go and see if I can change my mind. Regards

Comment: @Moo Wish luck with that! And please correct me if I'm wrong -- my impression about this book might had been skewed a bit :)